# Whitespace in JDBC URL

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm receiving this error in my application connecting to SQL Server Database:

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedExceptionCannot create JDBC driver of 
class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' for 
connect URL ' jdbcqlserver://myhost.com:8080;databaseName=myDB'
```

To update the string is kind of a lengthy process, so I'd like to identify the exact issue before I begin.

Would having white space in the URL cause this generic JDBC error?

Comment: The white space, and also this - jdbcqlserver is not a valid protocol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's difficult to change a database connection string, it's probably worth fixing that!

The whitespace could be a problem, but I don't think it's the only problem. This:

```
jdbcqlserver://myhost.com:8080;databaseName=myDB
```

Should probably look more like this:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://myhost.com:8080;databaseName=myDB
```

Answer (score 2):

The pattern is something like that:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://:server::port/:database?user=:user&password=:password
```

And don't let whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

You have"jdbcqlserver" is your database URI. I don't know SQLServer, but i'm guessing you want "`jdbcsqlserver`" instead.

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed that. Thank you very much

Comment: Too much time looking at the same line for a problem.